# I'm facing some Kotlin version issues in integrating the Zoom Video SDK in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, kotlin, build.gradle, version, release

The app was made using Flutter 3.7.7 and there is some depencies that are not working very well. When i run the app in my device via USB it's work perfectly. But always when i try to build a realese it's give me the following error:

```
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
Warning: elemento inesperado (uri:"", local:"extension-level"). Os elementos esperados s�o <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Warning: elemento inesperado (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Os elementos esperados s�o <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Warning: elemento inesperado (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Os elementos esperados s�o <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Note: C:\Users\F�bio Brasileiro\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.8.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\F�bio Brasileiro\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_zoom_videosdk-1.7.0\android\src\main\java\com\flutterzoom\videosdk\FlutterZoomVideoSdkPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.6.1/10f354fdb64868baecd67128560c5a0d6312c495/lifecycle-common-2.6.1.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1931011462a4d9592a65ca79f135961b/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.1-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/45c06e1bc3ce8b279ad7018bb66f9ff3/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/45c06e1bc3ce8b279ad7018bb66f9ff3/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/45c06e1bc3ce8b279ad7018bb66f9ff3/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4807bb09d91d466f6fc5f9f3df408fae/transformed/jetified-annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/512b308e558b698c198aa9f1eee669ce/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1-api.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/678015c9aca3e968a6d9928db7d1608c/transformed/core-1.10.1-api.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6977deb9a7d868c37c9f6104798efebb/transformed/jetified-activity-1.7.1-api.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6bc202d1bad6880c54a98b2a4eaa04d7/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9685c52f01c70977fb55c6c734ab64da/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.1-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9d35c3c8b815fe8e046a21f88a3c9d28/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.6.1-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was 
compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9d45c7c9432c37955baa87dd4286a6c8/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.10.1-api.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b27bd03e5857527e88d7071e7268f56b/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/F�bio Brasileiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e6a6792652668a54c226496db106f28c/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.6.1-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

This is my pubspeck.yaml:

```
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.4 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.4
  flutter_secure_storage: ^8.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.1
  google_sign_in: ^6.0.2
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.11
  postgres: ^2.6.1
  bcrypt: ^1.1.3
  flutter_animate: ^4.1.1+1
  page_transition: ^2.0.9
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+5
  validatorless: ^1.2.3
  crypto: ^3.0.3
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.6
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.6
  get_it: ^7.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0
  firebase_core: ^2.13.1
  flutter_zoom_videosdk: 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.6
  dart_jsonwebtoken: ^2.4.2
  shared_value: ^3.0.0
  events_emitter: ^0.5.2
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1


flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/app_icon/icon.png"
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  android: "launcher_icon"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#0472E8"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/app_icon/icon_android.png"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/tic_tac_toe/
    - assets/images/games_logos/
    - assets/images/checkers/
    - assets/images/payment/
    - assets/images/social_media_icons/
    - assets/app_icon/
    - assets/icons/
```

this is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The build release should be working.